# Outlook 2013: Programmaticaly reply to emails with HTML signature

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

My Outlook signature contains an image. When replying to plain-text emails, Outlook creates a plain-text email where the image in the signature is not included.

Instead of changing the format to HTML and afterwards inserting the signature once again manually I created the following plugin:

```
private void replyEmpty_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var mailItem = ((Inspector)e.Control.Context).CurrentItem;
    if (mailItem.BodyFormat != 2)
        mailItem.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem response = mailItem.Reply();
    response.Display();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(response);
}
```

The problem is that the `mailItem.BodyFormat` of the *original* message is set to HTML. Due to the change of the format, Outlook asks whether the changes should be saved:

> "The properties of the message ABC have been changed. Do you want to
>   save changes to this message?"

I want to avoid this extra click. So far, I couldn't find any alternative solutions. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `MailItem.Close(OlInspectorClose.olDiscard)`.

Comment: Thats it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also keep in mind that you don't have to display the message if you don't want to - the signature is added when you display the item (that is what you do) or when to access the MailItem.GetIInspector property.